# "Cast" to int in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing some simple game in Python 3.4. I am totally new in Python. Code below:

```
def shapeAt(self, x, y):
    return self.board[(y * Board.BoardWidth) + x]
```

Throws an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

For now I have found that this may happen when Python "thinks" that list argument is not an  integer. Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: what is the type of x and y???, if they are string use int(x) and int(y)

Comment: `(y * Board.BoardWidth) + x`  print and check value whether it is intger or float.

Comment: @TrzyGracje you want to save x,y as  int???

Comment: Can you show how you use the function, and where `Board.BoardWidth` comes from?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`int((y * Board.BoardWidth) + x)` use `int` to get nearest integer towards zero.

```
def shapeAt(self, x, y):
    return self.board[int((y * Board.BoardWidth) + x)] # will give you floor value.
```

and to get floor value use `math.floor`(by help of m.wasowski)

```
math.floor((y * Board.BoardWidth) + x)
```

Comment: @Trzy Gracje check the solution.

Comment: `int(x)` does not return floor value. It returns the nearest integer towards zero. So `int(-2.3)` returns `-2`, while `math.floor(-2.3)` returns `-3.0`.

Comment: @m.wasowski ohhh sorry i forgot about it.

Answer (score 6):

If `x`, `y` are numbers or strings representing number literals you can use [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) to cast to integer, while floating point values get floored:

```
>>> x = 1.5
>>> type(x)
<type 'float'>
>>> int(x)
1
>>> type(int(x))
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because your indices are of type `float` where these should be `ints` (because you are using them as array indices). I wouldn't use `int(x)`, I think you probably intended to pass an `int` (if not, use `return self.board[(int(y) * Board.BoardWidth) + int(x)]` of course).

You may also want to get floor value to get your index and here is how to do it:

```
import math

def shapeAt(self, x, y):
    return self.board[math.floor((y * Board.BoardWidth) + x)]
```

You can also use Python's [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function to identify type of your variables.

Answer (score 2):

what is the type of x and y you need to check that, then convert them to integer type using `int`:

```
def shapeAt(self, x, y):
    return self.board[(int(y) * Board.BoardWidth) + int(x)]
```

if you want to first store them:

```
def shapeAt(self, x, y):
    x,y = int(x),int(y)
    return self.board[(y * Board.BoardWidth) + x]
```

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay check the comment of OP

Comment: You don't check type in such a case in Python. You just try convert it, and catch exception if it occurs.

Comment: i told OP to check what type of data its getting , is it float or string, or list. so it will be more clear, and TypeError can be taken care of

Comment: Anyway, you still might get a `TypeError`, you don't know what type `Board.BoardWidth` is. If it is a `float`, you get a `float` as a result of expression in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just call a `int()` builtin:

```
def shapeAt(self, x, y):
    return self.board[int((y * Board.BoardWidth) + x))
```

However, if you want to use it to anything more than practise or dirty script for you, you should think of handling edge cases. What if you made mistake somewhere and put weird values as arguments?

The more robust solution would be:

```
def shapeAt(self, x, y):
    try:
        calculated = int((y * Board.BoardWidth) + x)
        # optionally, you may check if index is non-negative
        if calculated < 0:
            raise ValueError('Non-negative index expected, got ' +
                repr(calculated))
        return self.board[calculated]
    # you may expect exception when converting to int
    # or when index is out of bounds of your sequence
    except (ValueError, IndexError) as err:
        print('error in shapeAt:', err)
        # handle special case here
        # ...
        # None will be returned here anyway, if you won't return anything
        # this is just for readability:
        return None
```

If you are beginner, you might be suprising, but in Python negative indexes are perfectly valid, but they have special meanings. You should read about it, and decide if you want to allow them in your function (in my example they are disallowed).

You may also want to read about rules of converting to int:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

and consider, if for you it would not be better to user floor or ceiling, before you try to cast to int:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.floor

https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ceil

Just make sure, you have a `float` before calling those! ;)