# How to convert to int in python?

Tags: python

my name is Jay and I'm new to python and coding!

How can I convert the results to integer?

````
# This function adds two numbers
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

# This function subtracts two numbers
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

# This function multiplies two numbers
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

# This function divides two numbers
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y```

How can I go on?
````

Comment: You can use`int()`and put any number in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Cast" to int in Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244123/cast-to-int-in-python-3-4)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python float to int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569528/python-float-to-int-conversion)

Comment: Note that `int(3.9)` gives `3`.  In other words, `int()` truncates the fractional part of a number.  Adding `0.5` to your number before converting will make the rounding behave more intuitively (but I think not always correct).

Comment: Regarding division you would need to be careful since any quotient that is not equal to a integer would be rounded. (given that all input are integers and not floats... Otherwise Stevens comment above would need to be accounted in all cases.)

Comment: This is a duplicate and could easily be looked up in the documentation

Comment: Use // for integer division

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to convert to integer you must use `int(x)`
like this:

```
def my_function(x,y):
    return int(x / y)
```